# SharePoint Exports to Excel, can't I get directly in .xlsx file?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, excel

I am using SP 2013 foundation. I am able to export list into .iqy file. Which is good. But users wants directly .xlsx or .xls files. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you click on `Export to Excel`. Click on `Open` instead of save. The list would open in Excel. Then just do a `Save As` from excel `File` menu.

Comment: This is correct. The .iqy file is a connection to the SharePoint list. When you open it in Excel, Excel automatically downloads the list data into a new worksheet, and retains a connection to the list through the query file. Otherwise it is not possible to export directly to XLSX format.